# My mouse only works inside the current window

Tags: mouse, focus

Clicks anywhere outside of the active window are not registered. Even the title bar and menu buttons are unresponsive. Keyboard shortcuts that would normally get me to other windows also don't work. In order to get out of the active window I have to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>  until I can highlight a close button.

I'm dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Can you add hardware details to your question: type of mouse, type of graphics card, and make and model of your computer?

Comment: I don't know the real solution, but logging out and back in should resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

if your mouse is a touchpad, try attaching an external mouse.  You might have hit that magical function key to disable your touchpad.

If you're inside of a VM window you might want to hit Alt+Ctrl, right Ctrl, Left Ctrl or some variation.